# Can we compare statistically z-scores? Isn't their mean is always zero?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, inference, z-score

Let's say I have two variables of any distribution for which the population average and variance is assumed/known/fixed for some topic (common in psychology). Using this I can calculate z-scores for both variables and easily compare them.

But is it possible to perform any inference on such transformed data? Their population mean is assumed to be zero, even if sample one may be non-zero (collected all big values or all small ones).

I noticed some people tested it with t-test, while others told them it's pointless, because even if they find some statistically significant difference, it's a priori known to have both zero mean and unit variance. We could only compare the shapes of their empirical cumulative distribution functions, maybe quantiles, but not means, is this correct?

Comment: If you know the population means and variances... what else is there? Why are you doing inference?

Comment: It would be useful to know what variables you're actually thinking of.

Comment: Actually, it's theoretical that I know it. It's given to me already calculated. I was wondering about the general issue, where I personally don't know it and I'm interested in doing the inference. The data can be anything numeric, like one's abilities measured by some psychological questionnaire.

Comment: If you have two groups, *A*, and *B*, and you pool the values, and apply a *z*-transformation to the pooled values, then it makes potential sense to compare the resulting *z*-scores for the two groups, with e.g. a *t*-test.

Comment: I should also mention that a *z*-transformation is a linear transformation, so the distribution of the pooled *z* scores is similar to the distribution of the pooled original values.

Comment: Sal Mangiafico, thank you, the t-test doesn't apply in my case because of what you mentioned - totally different distributions and not even close to symmetry. But my concern was whether it makes sense anyway, if we a priori know, that all z-scores in population have fixed zero mean? Whatever we will find by the test, will be just artefact, because the inference from sample to population  won't agree with the population values equally being zero?

Comment: a) If the *t*-test doesn't apply, it doesn't apply.  Using a linear transformation won't help the situation.  b) If you have two groups and apply a *z*-transformation to each group separately, then both will have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of 1, so it's probably not helpful to compare the two.  ***However***, if you apply a *z*-transformation to the pooled values for the two groups, then a comparison makes sense if it made sense for the original values.  But as I said, since *z* is a linear transformation, the values will be different, but the shape of distribution won't change.

Comment: c) I would recommend you try what you are thinking with some toy values.  If I understand correctly, I think that no "artifact" will arise that will lead to improper inference.

Answer (score 1):

***Answer from comments:***

If you have two groups, *A* and *B*, and you pool the values, and apply a *z*-transformation to the pooled values, then it makes potential sense to compare the resulting *z*-scores for the two groups, with e.g. a *t*test.

A *z*-transformation is a linear transformation, so the distribution of the pooled *z* scores will be similar to the distribution of the pooled original values.

On the other hand, applying a *z* transformation to *A* and *B* separately will result in two groups of mean 0 and standard deviation 1, so it probably won't make sense to compare these.

I think it's helpful to play with these scenarios with toy data.